# Primary obstruction to the existence of a cross-section of $V_{n - q}(\omega)$ is a cohomology class in $H^{2q+2}(B, \pi_{2q+1} V_{n - q}(F))$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cohomology, characteristic-classes

Let $V_{n -  q}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ denote the complex Stiefel manifold consisting of all complex $(n - q)$-frames in $\mathbb{C}^n$, where $0 \le q < n$. This manifold is $2q$-connected, and$$\pi_{2q + 1} V_{n-q}(\mathbb{C}^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$Given a complex $n$-bundle $\omega$ over a CW-complex $B$ with typical fiber $F$, we can construct an associated bundle $V_{n-q}(\omega)$ over $B$ with typical fiber $V_{n-q}(F)$; consider the vector bundle $\text{Hom}(B \times \mathbb{C}^{n-q}, \omega)$ over $B$, and take the open subvariety of homomorphisms $u$ such that $u_b$ is injective for each $b \in B$. How do I see that the primary obstruction to the existence of a cross-section $V_{n-q}(\omega)$ is a cohomology class in$$H^{2q+2}(B, \pi_{2q+1}V_{n-q}(F))$$which can be identified with the Chern class $c_{q+1}(\omega)$?

**Edit.** To clarify what definition of the Chern classes I am using, I am using the one in Milnor-Stasheff where the top Chern class is the Euler class of the realification and the lower ones are defined by induction.

Comment: This seems to be your first displayed formula $+$ the definition of first obstruction. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: Read almost any textbook account of characteristic classes?  Milnor and Stasheff is good. But there are quite a few others.Davis and Kirk is another.  Shouldn't this question be closed?  The bounty does not allow it.

Comment: Indeed, this is Exercise 14.C in Milnor and Stasheff, copied over almost verbatim.

Comment: This is an interesting question even if it is an exercise from a textbook (I don't think it's too basic for MO), I would like to see an answer.

Comment: @John Frupp: What definition of the Chern classes are you using? I assume the one in Milnor and Stasheff (where the top Chern class is the Euler class of the realification and the lower ones are defined by induction)? Perhaps you can use that the Euler class is the primary obstruction to the existence of a nonzero section to prove this.

Comment: It should be noted that what you have described was historically the first *definition* of the Chern classes (see Steenrod's "Topology of Fibre Bundles" book, p210 and Appendix 10). It was only later that $H^*BU(n)$ was computed and people started defining Chern classes as the pullbacks of universal Chern classes. I don't know a reference in print where it is shown that the universal Chern classes are primary obstructions as above, though.

Comment: @MarkGrant Yeah, I am using definition in Milnor and Stasheff, as you mentioned.

Comment: Expanding on Mark's comment: You need to show that when $E = E' \oplus L$ where $L$ is a line bundle then the primary obstruction to finding a section of $V_{n-q}(E)$ is the same as the primary obstruction to finding a section of $V_{n-1-q}(E')$ as long as $q+1<\text{rk}(E)$. But there is a fibration of spaces over $B$ which induces an equivalence on the homotopy groups of fibers in the relevant degrees, and you can show that this implies the primary obstructions are the same. This completes the proof by the axiomatic characterization of Chern classes...

Comment: ... as long as you check that, in the case $q = n-1$, you get the Euler class. This is either true by definition or by checking against the universal example, where there's basically no room for the obstruction to be anything *but* the Euler class.

Comment: @user2503162: Certainly it's an interesting question and at a high enough level for MO. However, I for one do not want MO to become a repository for answers to textbook questions (for various reasons which should be obvious to anyone who has ever taught a course in mathematics).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fiber $V_{n - q}(F)$ is $2q$-connected, so it is not hard to construct a equivalence over the $(2q + 1)$-skeleton. We clearly can take sections over each vertex in the $0$-skeleton in the same connected component, then we can connect them on the 1-skeleton via paths because it is connected, then we can fill in with disks on the 2-skeleton because it is simply connected, and so forth. We then construct the "primary obstruction" as usual in $H^{2q + 2}(B, \pi_{2q + 1} V_{n - q}(F))$. Trying to extend to the $(2q + 1)$-skeleton gets us, through the attaching maps, an element$$\mathfrak{o}_{q + 1} \in H^{2q + 2}\left(B, \pi_{2q + 1}(V_{n - q}(F))\right) = H^{2q + 2}\left(B, \mathbb{Z}\right)$$in exactly the same way we discussed in class from traditional obstruction theory. According to Chapter 12 of Milnor, this construction is natural.

So in order to show that $\mathfrak{o}_{q + 1} = c_{q + 1}$, we can simply show it for the tautological bundle $\gamma^n$ on the infinite complex Grassmannian of $n$-planes, because any relation will pull back. By the results on the structure of the cohomology ring, we have$$\mathfrak{o}_{q + 1} = p(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_q) + \lambda c_{q + 1}$$for some unique polynomial $p$ and some unique constant $\lambda$. This relation we are taking at first to be for the tautological bundle $\gamma$, but by pullback, it has to hold for any bundle.

Let us look at the bundle $\gamma^q \oplus \epsilon^{n - q}$, over the infinite complex Grassmanninan of $q$-planes, where $\epsilon$ denotes the trivial line bundle. Evidently, this has $n - q$ independent linear sections, so $\mathfrak{o}_q$ should vanish. However, clearly $c_{q + 1} = 0$, because this is stably equivalent to a $q$-dimensional bundle, hence we get$$p\left(c_1\left(\gamma^q\right), c_2\left(\gamma^q\right), \ldots, c_q\left(\gamma^q\right)\right) = 0,$$so $p = 0$ because we know from structure results that there is no nontrivial polynoimal relation on these classes.

Lastly, we find that $\lambda = 1$. Let $\gamma_1$ be the tautological line bundle  over $\text{Gr}_\mathbb{C}(q + 1, q + 2)$, identified through orthogonal complements of the moduli as $\mathbb{C}P^{q + 1}$. Then let us look at$$\mathfrak{o}_{q + 1}\left(\gamma_1^{q + 1} \oplus \epsilon^{n - q - 1}\right) = \lambda c_{q + 1}\left(\gamma_1^{q + 1} \oplus \epsilon^{n - q - 1}\right).$$We want them to actually be equal to conclude that $\lambda = 1$. However, when $q + 1$ is the dimensional of the bundle, i.e. $q + 1 = n$, which is clear because the Chern class and the Euler class are both the obstruction class by Theorem 12.5 in Milnor, because a complex nonzero global section exists evidently if and only if a section of the bundle considered as a real bundle does. Otherwise, it follows because obstruction classes are clearly stable from their primary obstruction interpretation, i.e. we can add, delete trivial factors without modifying anything. Hence, we can reduce the case to $\mathfrak{o}_{q + 1}(\gamma_1^{q + 1}) = w_{q + 1}(\gamma_1^{q + 1})$, which follows again from the Euler class argument.

Comment: You say"We then construct the "primary obstruction" as usual in $H^{2q+2}(B,\pi_{2q+1}(V_{n−q}(F))$." Do you know of a reference where this primary obstruction for the existence of a global section is explained in the context of an arbitrary locally trivial fiber bundle?